# HttpClient & Rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I am working on a case where during a network connection we sometimes might have a limited internet connectivity where we unable to get response from the server or failed response as HttpError.
I hereby trying to ping the URL every second to check whether we are getting response or not, for this

I am trying this code, this is working fine in online method but when i am turning my internet of is doesn't return me false value.

**fetch-data.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Posts } from './posts';
import { Observable, interval, throwError, of } from 'rxjs';
import { take, exhaustMap, map, retryWhen, retry, catchError, tap, mapTo, } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FetchDataService {

  public url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

  constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getData() {
    const ob = interval(1000);
    return ob.pipe(
      exhaustMap(_ => {
        return this._httpClient.get<Posts[]>(this.url, { observe: 'response' });
      }),
      map(val => {
        if (val.status === 200)
          return true;
        throw val;
      }),
      retryWhen(errors => {
        return errors.pipe(map(val => {
          if (val.status === 0)
            return false;
        }))
      })
    );
  }


  // private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
  //   if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
  //     // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
  //     console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
  //   } else {
  //     // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
  //     // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
  //     console.error(
  //       `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
  //       `body was: ${error.error}`);
  //     if (error.status !== 200)
  //       return of(false);
  //   }
  //   // return an observable with a user-facing error message
  //   return throwError(
  //     'Something bad happened; please try again later.');

  // };

}
```

**pulldata.component.html**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FetchDataService } from '../fetch-data.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Posts } from '../posts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pulldata',
  templateUrl: './pulldata.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pulldata.component.css']
})
export class PulldataComponent implements OnInit {

  public data;
  public error = '';

  constructor(private _fecthDataServe: FetchDataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._fecthDataServe.getData().subscribe(val => {
      this.data = val;
      console.log(this.data);
    });

  }

}
```

what would be the best solution to check the internet connectivity in this manner?

Answer (score 2):

My personal preference would be to not do this with HTTP because of data overhead. Every HTTP request will contain cookie data and other headers that are often useless in these kinds of scenarios.

Is it possible for you to use [Web Sockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket)? With these, you can open up a connection to the server that, unlike HTTP, doesn't have to close. It can remain open forever. And you can subscribe to events to get notified about connection losses. Web Sockets also have the added benefit that it's a new protocol based on TCP, it's not HTTP, resulting in a lot less network data will have to be send.

```
let socket = new WebSocket('wss://yourserver/socket...');
socket.addEventListener('open', () => console.log('connection has been opened'));
socket.addEventListener('close', () => console.log('connection has been closed'));
```

In your situation, you might also want to check out [the Reconnecting WebSocket](https://github.com/joewalnes/reconnecting-websocket), which reconnects when the connection drops. You could also write this small wrapper yourself, of course.

Also, what might even be a simpler solution. You can subscribe to `online`/`offline` events on the `window` object: [read more on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/Online_and_offline_events)

```
function updateOnlineStatus(event) {
    var condition = navigator.onLine ? "online" : "offline";

    // ...do something with the new status
}

window.addEventListener('online',  updateOnlineStatus);
window.addEventListener('offline', updateOnlineStatus);
```

Both of these solutions should be easily wrappable in an Angular service, but let me know if that works out and/or if these solutions are an option for you.